# How to fix error NumberFormatException when use c:foreach in jsp

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

**Issues**

> I have a error when display record, I try varStatus but that still this error, What i should do to fix that bug??
>   In a controller of another entity, it work!
>   Tks a alot!!!

**Repository**

```
public List<RecordFormHomePage> topStaff() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<RecordFormHomePage> recordsList = session.createSQLQuery("select `StaffId`,sum(case when `Type`=1 then 1 else 0 end) as achievement, sum(case when `Type`=0 then 1 else 0 end) as mistake, sum(case when `Type`=1 then 1 else 0 end)-sum(case when `Type`=0 then 1 else 0 end) as total from Records group by `StaffId`\n" + 
            "").list();

    return recordsList;
}
```

**Service**

```
@Transactional
public List<RecordFormHomePage> topStaff() {

    return recordRepository.topStaff();
}
```

**JSP**

```
<c:forEach var="staff" items="${TopStaff }" varStatus="stt">
    <tr>
        <td>${staff.stt.total }</td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

**Controller**

```
  public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("TopStaff", recordService.topStaff());
    return "/homepage/index";
}
```

**RecordFormHomePage**

```
public class RecordFormHomePage implements Serializable{
int StaffId;
int Achievement;
int mistake;
int total;
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "stt"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:144)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:61)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.homepage.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(index_jsp.java:810)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.homepage.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:266)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

tks so much!!!

Comment: Q: Are *ALL* values of `${staff.stt.total}` throwing "NumberFormatException", or only *SOME* records?  Q: If only "some" records, I'm guessing maybe ".total" is "null" for those records.  Please verify this.  In any case, your "topStaff()" service is responsible for detecting "bad data" and responding appropriately.  You might want to set total "0" if null.

Comment: total is not null, i try another record but still response that error. I print data query in console is ok :<

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your .jsp might look something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Number</th><th>Name</th></tr>
   <c:forEach var="staff" items="${TopStaff}" varStatus="loop">
   <tr>
      <td>${loop.index}</td><td>${staff.name}</td></tr>
       ...
   </c:forEach>
   ...
```

This assumes:

- "TopStaff" is a list of staff members.
- "staff" is the current staff record in the loop
- The properties in the "staff" object are all valid (no "bad data")
- `${TopStaff}`, `${staff.name}`, etc. don't have any "blank" spaces inside the braces.
- You reference a valid varStatus property like "loop.index", "loop.begin", "loop.end", etc.

'Hope that helps...